Can I automate the Firefox security settings-Selenium- Robot framework
I'm currently engaged in GUI automation where the use of a CA certificate and private key is necessary for login purposes. The application is hosted on a server enabled with MTLS. I'm exploring the possibility of automating Firefox browser's security settings to seamlessly incorporate the required certificate. Does anyone have experience or insights on achieving this? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
    OpenBrowser    about:preferences    firefox
    Wait Until Element Is Enabled    //*[@id="category-privacy"]    30
    Click Element    //*[@id="category-privacy"]
    Click Element    //*[@id="viewSecurityDevicesButton"]
    ${handles}    Get Window Handles
    log    ${handles}
    
    FOR    ${handle}    IN    @{handles}
        Switch Window    ${handle}
        ${title}    Get Title
        Log To Console    ${title}
        Wait Until Element Is Enabled    //*[@id="devicemanager"]    30
        Click Element    //*[@id="load_button"]
    END

